# Ler dados de um banco SQLite 3 no Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, sqlite3

Estou começando em Python e banco de dados e me surgiram três dúvidas!

1. Por exemplo, dentro do meu banco de dados tenho uma coluna "nome". 
   Apenas para ilustrar, digamos que eu queira pegar o conteúdo da coluna "nome" correspondente ao id= 1 e jogar numa variável do Python chamada "nomeCliente"?
2. Como faço para listar o número total de registros existentes?
3. Caso eu queira fazer um botão no Python que navegue entre os registros Como deveria ser feito? Tem algo do tipo cursor.next e cursor.previous, por exemplo?

Muito obrigado, pessoal!

Answer (score -1):

Fiz desta forma, acredito que seja o mais simples, utiliza mais código Python do que recursos do SQL.

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect("teste.db")
cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute("create table if not exists testes ( nome varchar(50));")

for i in range(1, 1001):
    cursor.execute("insert into testes values (' testando like a boss %s')" %i)

cursor.execute("select * from testes")

count = 0

for row in cursor.fetchall():
    print(row)
    count += 1
    if (count % 10) == 0:
        escolha = input('c - continuar, p - parar? \n')
        if escolha.lower() == 'c':
            pass
        elif escolha.lower() == 'p':
            break
conn.commit()

conn.close()
```

Espero que ajude.

Comment: Olá @afonso.prog ! Beleza?
Cara, no fim eu consegui assim: 

#move para o último registro cadastrado:
        cursor.execute("SELECT idCliente FROM clientes ORDER BY idCliente desc limit 1")

 #joga para uma variável no python e tira as aspas e parênteses:
        codCliente = " ".join(map(str, cursor.fetchone()))

 #atribui aos textfields do programa o valor da variável armazenada
            self.ids.tf_codCliente.text = codCliente

Mas muito obrigado pela ideia, também muito boa!!